Extracting screenshots from an Exam Paper for questions and their parts
I want to extract screenshots of questions from a pdf exam paper. I wanted the question and its parts to be separated, so the actual question's introduction would be in a different screen shot and the parts of the question would be in other screenshots. I tried using pdfminer, but it didn't seem to work out so well. My problem is not being able to identify what is a question and what isn't.
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Any

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBoxHorizontal, LTTextLineHorizontal, LTChar
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

file = open("./PhysicsPdfs/9702_m23_qp_22.pdf", "rb")

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(resource_manager, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(file)

textbox = False
textbox_text = ""
q_num = 1
for p, page in enumerate(list(pages)[:-3]):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for l_obj in layout:
        if isinstance(l_obj, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            x, y, text = l_obj.bbox[0], l_obj.bbox[3], l_obj.get_text()
            if isinstance(l_obj, Iterable) and isinstance(list(l_obj)[0], LTTextLineHorizontal) and text.startswith(str(q_num)):
                q_num += 1
                if len(l_obj) == 1:
                    if list(l_obj)[0].get_text() == text:
                        try:
                            numq = int(list(l_obj)[0].get_text())
                            if len(str(numq)) == 1:
                                print(f"Found Question {numq} on page {p+3} from the text: {text}")
                        except ValueError:
                            continue

This is the code I used, but it doesn't even find the actual question numbers. My thought was that if I can manage to find each question's number, I could find the coordinates of the question (at least its height in the page) and use that to get a snapshot. So I tried finding the question numbers since I noticed some of them are in their own individual LTTextBoxHorizontal. Though some were also not in their own individual LTTextBoxHorizontal, they were rather in the same LTTextBoxHorizontal as their first part (a), but I decided to get to finding ones in individual LTTextBoxHorizontal. This clearly didn't work as it doesn't return the questions but rather returns other numbers on the page.
Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? In the end, I just want to extract each question and its parts from the pdf. AI is not an option for this since I don't really want to have to spend money, and AI also seems unreliable.
An example input can be found here

Could you add you import statements,please. Do you have an example input pdf?

Oops, I was going to add them, will do. Give me a second

An example input pdf can be found here
https://papers.gceguide.net/A%20Levels/Physics%20(9702)/2023/9702_m23_qp_22.pdf

For me it looks like the source was a LaTex document. Maybe easier to use that? Otherwise you have to split the pages, because each new puestion starts on top of the page. Is tesseract an option?

Didn't notice that the questions start from the top, great find. How would I use LaTex to extract these questions? Do you mind elaborating? I've never actually used LaTex before so it's a first.
